# Using ag-grid with many rows and Autosave

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid (javascript) to display a large amount of rows (about 3,000 or more) and allow the user to enter values and it should auto-save them as the user goes along. My current strategy is after detecting that a user makes a change to save the data for that row.

The problem I'm running into is detecting and getting the correct values after the user enters a value. The *onCellKeyPress* event doesn't get fired for Backaspace or Paste. However if I attach events directly to DOM fields to catch key presses, I don't know how to know what data the value is associated with. Can I use *getDisplayedRowAtIndex* or such to be able to reliably do this reliably? What is a good way to implement this?

**EDIT: Additional detail**

My current approach is to capture **onCellEditingStopped** and then getting the data from the event using event.data[event.column.colId]. Since I only get this event when the user moves to a different cell and not just if they finish typing I also handle the **onCellKeyPress** and get the data from event.event.target (since there is no event.data when handling this event). Here is where I run into a hard-to-reproduce problem that event.event.target is sometimes undefined.

I also looked at using **forEachLeafNode** method but it returns an error saying it isn't supported when using infinite row model. If I don't use infinite mode the load time is slow.

Comment: Not sure what challenge you are facing.. You can use `cellEditingStopped` event once you are done with editing for the cell and make ajax call to update the data at the server: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/. Reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can understand and help you easily.

Comment: What if they never move off the cell? 

If I try to catch other events like onCellKeyPress and then get the event.event.target it fails sometimes in a way that I can't reproduce but happens on some of our customer machines intermittently.

Comment: Could it be something related to how the infinite data model handles the DOM elements?

Comment: Glancing at the docs, wouldn't `cellValueChanged` be a more appropriate event to use?

Comment: Yes, that is much better and I'll accept if given as answer. For 100% bounty, how can I make it so it will save the value even if the user doesn't leave the cell? I've turned on stopEditingWhenGridLosesFocus but if the user doesn't actually leave it won't save the value. For example if they just hit refresh page keystroke.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you can bind to the onCellKeyDown event.  This is sometimes undefined because on first keydown the edit of agGrid will switch from the cell content to the cell editor.  You can wrap this around to check if there is a cell value or cell textContent.

```
function onCellKeyDown(e) {
  console.log('onCellKeyDown', e);
  if(e.event.target.value) console.log(e.event.target.value)
  else console.log(e.event.target.textContent)
}
```

See https://plnkr.co/edit/XhpVlMl7Jrr7QT4ftTAi?p=preview

Comment: I'm awarding the bounty to this since it can explain the issue I was facing, although I haven't verified yet. James Tomasino actually gave the main part of the answer I needed in the comment response.

Answer (score 0):

As been pointed out in comments, `onCellValueChanged` might work, however

> After a cell has been changed with default editing (i.e. not your own custom cell renderer), the cellValueChanged event is fired.

```js
var gridOptions = {
    rowData: null,
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    defaultColDef: {
        editable: true, // using default editor
        width: 100
    },
    onCellEditingStarted: function(event) {
        console.log('cellEditingStarted', event);
    },
    onCellEditingStopped: function(event) {
        console.log('cellEditingStopped', event);
    },
    onCellValueChanged: function(event) {
      console.log('cellValueChanged', event);
    }
};
```

another option could be to craft your own editor and inject it into cells:

```js
function MyCellEditor () {}

// gets called once before the renderer is used
MyCellEditor.prototype.init = function(params) {
    this.eInput = document.createElement('input');
    this.eInput.value = params.value;
    console.log(params.charPress);  // the string that started the edit, eg 'a' if letter a was pressed, or 'A' if shift + letter a
    this.eInput.onkeypress = (e) => {console.log(e);} // check your keypress here
};

// gets called once when grid ready to insert the element
MyCellEditor.prototype.getGui = function() {
    return this.eInput;
};

// focus and select can be done after the gui is attached
MyCellEditor.prototype.afterGuiAttached = function() {
    this.eInput.focus();
    this.eInput.select();
};

MyCellEditor.prototype.onKeyDown = (e) => console.log(e);

// returns the new value after editing
MyCellEditor.prototype.getValue = function() {
    return this.eInput.value;
};
//// then, register it with your grid:
var gridOptions = {
    rowData: null,
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    components: {
        myEditor: MyCellEditor,
    },
    defaultColDef: {
        editable: true,
        cellEditor: 'myEditor',
        width: 100
    },
    onCellEditingStarted: function(event) {
        console.log('cellEditingStarted', event);
    },
    onCellEditingStopped: function(event) {
        console.log('cellEditingStopped', event);
    }
};
```